# problem with html2pdf (vanilla js), how to style generated pdf?

Tags: pdf, html2pdf

I have a button "download" in my html, after I click on this button, pdf file is generated.
Code is given below:
let options = {
margin: 0,
filename: "myfile.pdf",
html2canvas: { scale: 3 },
jsPDF: {
unit: "in",
format: "letter",
orientation: "portrait",
},
};

```
let downloadButton = document.querySelector(".download");
downloadButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
let pdfDoc = document.querySelector(".divforPDF");

html2pdf().from(pdfDoc).set(options).save();
});
```

everything works perfectly fine, until I started testing it on different screensizes. If the webpage has no scroll, pdf file looks good, with no issues, but as soon as scroll appears, pdf file is a total mess, there is a huge blank space on top of the file and content is not fully given, just part of it, although there is enough space on the bottom of teh psf file.
Could you please give me some advice how to fix it?Do I have to style pdf? how ? I tried to find some tutorials, but unfortunately,problem remains unsolved.